# Anylogic Database how to write in the same line?

Tags: database, sql-insert, anylogic

I am working in a university project and I have come across this problem. I am quite new to anylogic so I apologize for my ignorance.

We want to write data from various timeMeasureEnd block into a database table. We have columns end1; end2; end3; end4 and end5.

We have been using

```
insertInto(endtimes)
  .columns(endtimes.endX)
  .values(timeMeasureEndX.time())
  .execute();
```

where `X` changes from one block to another. However, this creates a new line in the database table for every new value.

We also tried to use this piece of code for the 2nd to 5th values

```
update(starttimes)
   .where(starttimes.start2.isNull())
   .set(starttimes.start2, startTimeP2j.time())
   .execute();
```

In an attempt to only affect the values that are null and have a corresponding first value. However, given that the first values of the second job can come before the second values of the first job, this can affect every value down the line.

How can I insert values into a specific row? If that is impossible, how can I only alter one value at a time with the second bit of code?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Best regards,
Diogo

Comment: Can you clarify the actual problem? What do you want to achieve, and what does it currently look like? Share some (fake) dbase screenshots, ideally.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a 'key' column in order to be able to update a row with several values as they become available. To clarify: is there some common piece of information like an id number of a piece of work or something else other than time that is stored in that record and can be used to uniquely identify it?

Alternatively, the table can have 5 rows, each containing the object name (i.e. 'end1','end2'...) and time value.